# Append text to a string from a tcpclient?

Tags: .net, vb.net

For some reason I can't append text to data I get from a tcpclient stream I have.

```
Dim Client As New TcpClient("server", port)
Dim stream As NetworkStream = Client.GetStream()
Dim receiveBytes As [Byte]() = New [Byte](Client.ReceiveBufferSize) {}
Dim returnData As [String] = [String].Empty
stream.Read(receiveBytes, 0, CInt(Client.ReceiveBufferSize))
returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes)
MsgBox(returnData + "hello")
```

The message box will only contain the returnData string without the hello.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're ignoring the return value of `Stream.Read`. You won't always receive a *full* buffer at a time - and whatever else is present will be 0. That means you'll have Unicode "null" characters (0) at the end of `returnData`, and Windows treats those as string terminators.

Change the two lines just before the end to:

```
Dim bytesRead = stream.Read(receiveBytes, 0, CInt(Client.ReceiveBufferSize))
Dim returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes, 0, bytesRead)
```

(That's having removed the previous declaration of `returnData` - there's no point in declaring a variable and giving it a dummy value when you're about to replace that value.)

(Note that this is assuming the data really *is* in ASCII... is it, definitely?)

Comment: Yes I send the data myself as ASCII. Thanks for the response, worked perfectly.